# Accelerometer process

Tags: flash, air, signals, accelerometer

I am developing a mobile game by flash air. I wish to use an accelerometer to control the avatar in my game. I ran into the trouble of removing the noise in the accelerometer data. I tried to get the average value of the last accelerometer data with the previous value to remove the noise. But I lost the sensitive response of the user's input. Otherwise, I tried to respond sensitively, but then the noise will cause the avatar's trembling. I have no idea how to adjust an accelerometer process to make it perfect. I found that the accelerometer procession of "Ridiculous Fishing" looks great. If anyone can tell me how to implement a perfect accelerometer process like that in "Ridiculous Fishing", thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather general question. For simple low-pass filters like the moving average method that you tried, there's always going to be quite pronounced trade-off between smoothness and latency. Regarding a more "perfect" method, without more details of your exact problem, I can only suggest that you experiment with more sophisticated filters, for example a higher order [Butterworth Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter) (try this first), or a [Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) (try this if you're able to formulate your actual problem as such). Both are quite well-known algorithms, and you should be able to easily find existing implementations.